# Area of filled Julia set

Tags: fractals

This is a vague question, and I know nothing about this area.

We fix some $c\in\mathbb C$ and iterate the map $z\mapsto z^2+c$. This gives some filled Julia set, i.e. the set of points $z\in\mathbb C$ so that the orbit of $z$ is bounded. For example, for $c=0$ this is the closed unit disk. I'm wondering if anyone knows about any relationship between the area of the Julia set and the position of $c$ in the Mandelbrot set.

Comment: http://lodev.org/cgtutor/juliamandelbrot.html

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/38114/area-of-filled-julia-sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem A-1 in Milnor's book *Dynamics in one complex variable* contains a formula for the area expressed as a series based on Gronwall's area theorem:
$$
 \pi (1 - |a_2|^2 - 3|a_4|^2 - 5|a_6|^2 - \cdots)
$$
The series is said to converge slowly. The coefficients of the series can be easily computed recursively though by solving
$$
 \psi(w^2) = \psi(w)^2+c
$$
for
$$
\def\F#1{\frac{a_{#1}}{w^{#1}}}
 \psi(w) = w(1 + \F2 + \F4 + \F6 + \cdots)
$$

Here is graph of the area for $c \in [-2,0.25]$ obtained by truncating the series at several points (the better estimates are the inner ones):

$\hskip 4cm$ [image]

The topmost graph represents the estimate $A \le \pi (1 - |a_2|^2) = \pi (1 - |c|^2/4)$.